# Best practice to label thumb scoopers/dishers

Tags: utensils

I've included an image because I am not sure of the best word to use.  Portion scooper I guess is what you might call them.

What is the best way to label them?  I've got about 4 in my drawer, and I am never sure which to use when it comes time to cook (and usually have to measure by adding water, then drying).

I figure maybe some white tape, or a label maker, but these methods all seem to get wrecked by the dishwasher.  My wife suggested to handwash them all, but no.  If it can go in the dishwasher, it will.

[image: scooper/disher]

Comment: It’s called a ‘disher’ which my phone refuses to accept or a ‘scooper’. Some companies color code the handles, and some etch the size on the sweep.. try squeezing it part way and look.  They might be something ‘2TB’ or a number.. that number is fractions of a quart, I think.  (So how many scoops you should get out of a quart; see https://pastrieslikeapro.com/numbers-and-sizes-of-disher-scoopers/ )

Comment: What is the purpose of labeling?  To identify their _capacity_?

Comment: Another question about [disher sizes](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/86595/what-size-disher-makes-1-inch-balls-of-dough). Here's a [picture](https://i.imgur.com/11IrYg7.jpg) of the number on the sweep of one of my dishers.

Comment: @JohnGordon, yes.  Specifically the number of fluid ounces.

Comment: None of them have markings already.  The 1 TBSP and 2 TSBP are the same manufacturer, and they look nearly the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would photograph them lined up together, and print that out, labelling it with the bowl width (so you can check with a ruler), empty weight  (so you can check with scales) and capacity (because that's what you really need to know).  Hopefully with the picture alone you can identify which one of the set to use, but the empty weight or width would allow you to check  if most were in the dishwasher already.

Alternative, colour code them with cable ties (zip ties) in different colours.  On most such scoops there's somewhere they'll wrap round the handle with getting in the way.  Trim off the loose end with wire cutters (poultry shears will go through them, but don't leave such a nice edge).  Cable ties are made of the same sorts of nylon used in cooking utensils, and stand up fine to dishwasher.  The upper spray arm of mine is held together with some, that have kept their colour for years, after I had to open it up in a way it wasn't designed for to clear a blocked hole.

If you had a flat bit of metal, you could try to get your hands on some metal stamps, that you'd hit with a hammer.  But you'd need good support from behind and the one pictured doesn't look suitable

Comment: Instead of using a picture, it would be easier to make a gauge. Take some thick cardboard or plywood. Create holes, each the size of the scoop's bowl, and number them. Then grab the scoop you think is the right one, and see which hole it fits through.

Comment: @rumtscho good thinking.  I'd want to make the gauge itself washable, which would be harder, but card could be replaced.  You could possibly just print circles the right size and lay the scoops on top to check; that could be laminated and wipe-clean.  A real neat-freak would make a custom storage solution the doubled as a gauge.  Each scoop would be stored in a custom pocket in foam, like the tool drawers in work.  But my stuff expands to the available space and I'm not that tidy anyway

Comment: I also find the storage solution impractical. I thought of suggesting creating labeled spaces for the scoops, like four labeled hooks on a cabinet wall, but it not only wastes space, it will also be vulnerable to mismatching the tools to the hooks. Foam inserts would really be a neat freak's solution :) As for a washable gauge with holes, one could buy plastic sheets that are sturdy enough to not crumple or tear apart - maybe even a laminating sheet without anything laminated inside. There are a lot of solutions.

Comment: new gauge idea: make labelled balls which fit into each scoop. There are many ways to do it, especially if the balls themselves don't have to be washable. You could string them up so you don't have to hunt for the set through the whole kitchen drawer.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisH, I was thinking about this approach.  I have a tray of oils, and I keep a list in the drawer to remember the ones I infrequently use.  I'll do the same with the scoopers.

Answer (score 14):

I mark my kitchen tools using a [scriber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriber).

[image: Photo of a scriber on a wooden table. It's a pencil-shaped metal holder with a sharp tip. Photo taken by me.]

It's just a sharp stylus point made of some hard metal (tungsten carbide or similar) in a pencil-like holder.  You use it like a pencil to etch lettering into  metal, hard plastic, or glass (watch for chips though).

You can buy one at a hardware store or online for less than USD 10.  Once you have one, you'll probably find all other kinds of things around the house that you want to mark.  You can usually replace the point when it gets dull (though they last a long time).  Just don't get it mixed up with your iPad stylus!

Comment: This is some excellent intel.  TIL...

Comment: This is how I marked my scoop collection, except I used an electric engraving tool instead.

Comment: Depending on the material the utensil is made of, this may remove its stainlessness, though. If it’s only stainless steel–plated, scratching through the outer surface may get you through to a corrodible material, and dishwashing will then eventually lead to rust spreading on your formerly pristine utensil.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question, and a somewhat difficult one, because dishwasher detergent is really aggressive stuff.

I've had success with fine-tip permanent felt-tip pens, but not all brands will work, and you can't predict the outcome when you're shopping for pens.

A workable and non-destructive alternative is nail polish. You won't be able to write the exact volume on the scoop, but you can color-code them using a dot or two on the handle. It can chip away with time, but seeing that scoops are usually not in daily use, it may last long enough for your needs.

The really certain solutions would be etching or engraving. You could etch them yourself, if you're willing to work with a strong acid. If the handles are plastics, ask in an electronics shop for the stuff they etch PCBs with. If they're metal, you would need 25% HCl or something similarly strong, and you should be able to achieve a visible discoloration even on stainless steel. Again, nail polish can be useful here, in this case to apply the template for the etching (at least it works with the PCB flux, I don't know if it stands up to HCl).

As for engraving, I don't know of a way to do it at home - even if you had a tool for it, it would be difficult to actually write any kind of text without spending months of training. But since all you need is a way to differentiate only four items, you can just use a drill to make a distinctive pattern of a few holes in the handle. Or you can go to a professional to engrave numbers, especially if it's metal.

The last option I'd consider is to try super strong mounting glue like Sikaflex to add something visually distinctive, like a colored bead, to the handles, so it would look like color-coded fondue sticks. I haven't tried this in a dishwasher, but it really works as advertised in difficult environments.

If you have handles made from a known plastics, you can consider if it's suitable for plastics welding. You probably won't even need to weld anything to the handles, just use differently colored filament on each scoop.

If you have the exact same model as shown in the picture, the easiest solution might be yarn. Crochet a tight ring of yarn between the handle and the guard to color-code the scoops, and it shouldn't slip away. If you can't crochet, you can also try winding it at that place tightly until you have a snug, nicely visible band of color.

Comment: Permanent pens heavily depend on the plastic they're on.  I use a (blue) Sharpie for labelling freezer boxes.  On many it's very faint after the 2nd time through the dishwasher.  On others it lasts ages.  It lasts longer on more textured surfaces.  Both nail polish and pens would survive better in an engraved mark in the grooves of a handle like those pictured.  A Dremel rotary tool will engrave, though it take a bit of practice. Vibrating engraving tools are better as they don't try to pull themselves across the workpiece.

Comment: @ChrisH I've never tried engraving. I've always imagined it to be a skill that needs lots of practice, but maybe I'm wrong - and admittedly, my fine motor skills are not especially well-honed. If the OP already has a Dremel, he might already know how likely he is to be up to the task. And indeed, the combination of numerals engraving and color would be best for durability+usability. So maybe just try it (or consider if you have a dentist neighbor you can ask :) )

Comment: *Legible* engraving with a Dremel could be done with a few minutes of practice on comparable material. Tidy is a bit harder!

Comment: Also good suggestions, @rumtscho.  I will go with Chris' suggestion (less destructive/elbow grease).

Comment: @ChrisH: As a very primitive form of engraving, I just use a scriber (see my answer).  You don't get beautiful calligraphy, but you do get readable permanent lettering without needing special skills or elaborate equipment.

Comment: @NateEldredge they're slightly easier to use than rotary engraving, but I've found the lines to be too fine for labelling that you want to be readable at a glance at arms length. Unless you go over several times

Comment: For plastic handles you can also "engrave" (loosely defined) using a soldering iron. Or create makeshift branding irons out of wire.